# Frequent unexpected requests logged by Rails app in EC2 - from Amazon public IP addresses - Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm running a rails app that writes files to Amazon S3. Now I have uniqorn running as server and see all lots of request coming in from different amazon AWS IP-addresses.

Here is a part of my log file:

```
Started GET "/" for 54.245.168.11 at 2016-10-02 18:30:50 +0000

Processing by StaticPagesController#home as */*

  Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (0.2ms)

  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.1ms)

  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.3ms)

Completed 200 OK in 3ms (Views: 3.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Started GET "/" for 54.252.254.235 at 2016-10-02 18:30:51 +0000

Processing by StaticPagesController#home as */*

  Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (0.2ms)

  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)

  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.3ms)

Completed 200 OK in 3ms (Views: 3.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Started GET "/" for 54.232.40.107 at 2016-10-02 18:30:52 +0000

Processing by StaticPagesController#home as */*

  Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (0.7ms)

  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.2ms)

  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.8ms)

Completed 200 OK in 12ms (Views: 10.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Started GET "/" for 54.252.79.139 at 2016-10-02 18:30:52 +0000

Processing by StaticPagesController#home as */*

  Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (0.7ms)

  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.3ms)

  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.5ms)

Completed 200 OK in 13ms (Views: 11.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Started GET "/" for 54.250.253.203 at 2016-10-02 18:30:52 +0000

Processing by StaticPagesController#home as */*

  Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (0.5ms)

  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.1ms)

  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.3ms)

Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 3.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Started GET "/" for 54.243.31.203 at 2016-10-02 18:30:54 +0000

Processing by StaticPagesController#home as */*

  Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (0.5ms)

  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)

  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.3ms)

Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 3.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I can't find any info on this online. My application isn't live yet, so nobody looks at it. Why is AWS doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are [Route 53 Health Checks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-failover.html), which are a different type of health check than the health checks configured in Elastic Load Balancer (ELB), and different from the EC2 instance health and reachability checks that EC2 automatically performs on every EC2 instance.

Take a look at the published [AWS IP Address Ranges](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-ip-ranges-json/), and you'll find that these match up to the address blocks specifically assigned to Route 53 Health Checks, quite nicely.

For example, this request...

```
Started GET "/" for 54.232.40.107 at 2016-10-02 18:30:52 +0000
```

...matches this entry...

```
{
  "ip_prefix": "54.232.40.64/26",
  "region": "sa-east-1",
  "service": "ROUTE53_HEALTHCHECKS"
},
```

...because `54.232.40.64/26` is the [CIDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) spec for the IP address block from 54.232.40.64 through 54.232.40.127.

If you configured a Route 53 health check against your stack, then you probably have your answer, at this point.

Route 53 Health Checks are often used to drive the logic of complex DNS configurations, such as in cases where there are multiple candidate servers geographically distributed, and you want to control the answer returned by DNS based on the health of the servers... but they can also be used for monitoring latency and application performance (measuring TCP connect time and time-to-first-byte, as well as availability), tied into CloudWatch alarms, and used to drive scaling and other logic.  If you configured anything like this, the question may be solved.

But if you didn't, this could be a case of another AWS user who has configured health checks against an IP address they were formerly using, or has configured the checks against your IP address or hostname by simple mistake.

If that is the case, you'll need to inspect the request headers from the incoming request.  You'll find something like this:

```
User-Agent: Amazon Route 53 Health Check Service; ref:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx; report http://amzn.to/zzzzzzz
```

With these values in hand, along with the other headers and any relevant log entries, you can visit the "report" URL provided in the headers you captured, (it's similar to the one I've shown above, captured from my logs, but sanitized since it seems to be generic, but I'm not certain -- the link in my logs redirects me [here](https://aws.amazon.com/forms/route53-unwanted-healthchecks)) and submit a request for AWS to work with you to to eliminate the unwanted health checks.

But first, try this...

Take the value immediately after "ref:" and create a URL from it, using this template:

`https://console.aws.amazon.com/route53/healthchecks/home#/details/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx`

(Replace xxxx with your ref:, excluding the actual string `ref:`).

If the health check is from your own AWS account, and you're logged into the console, and have permission to view it, then this crafted link should bring the health check right up for you to view.  If you get an error that you are "not authorized to access this resource," then the health check is not from your AWS account, or you aren't a privileged user on the AWS account and thus may lack the ability to view it.